# Destacar termos pesquisados no PDF

Tags: php, pdf

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em PHP de GED (Gestão Eletrônica de Documentos). Nele preciso fazer a busca pelo conteúdo do PDF e listá-los (até ai tudo bem), mas quando abrir os PDF's listados, necessito destacar as palavras dentro do PDf que o usuário inseriu na busca. Fiz uma pesquisa e não encontrei nada que me daria uma noção de como fazer isto!